# Message between PHP server and Android app

Tags: php, android, web-services

Well let's question, I need to develop for my term paper a messaging system where I can from my site / php server send messages to my android application. I know the question is very broad, but I wanted to know the simplest way to achieve this. Someone could show me some method or API to achieve.
PS: Sorry for english

I thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to receive messages in your app while the app is terminated or running you could use the [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client).

*Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is a cross-platform messaging solution that lets you reliably deliver messages at no cost.
Using FCM, you can notify a client app that new email or other data is available to sync. You can send notification messages to drive user reengagement and retention. For use cases such as instant messaging, a message can transfer a payload of up to 4KB to a client app.*